# Need regex to disallow unicode characters from a form text area using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, unicode

I am trying to disallow unicode characters from a form text area where the data is either entered manually or copy-pasted. I tried the following regex -

```
regex: /^[A-z&#209;&#241;0-9]*$/i
```

This is disallowing all the special characters like hyphen(-) too. But what I need is to remove only the unicode character like the diamond symbol in this data - pr�s-*.

Can someone please help. If there is any plugin that can achieve this, please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not what you want to hear but "no you don't". You need to support unicode, because the world you live in uses it. That diamond symbol is a sign that your call chain is converting the data improperly. Fix *that* instead.

Comment: okay.. I need an error handler that detects if a unicode character is present in the text box and gives an intimation. Can you help me out on that please?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You might not want to hear this. But Context is the world. Sometimes opening a nut with a sledge hammer IS the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @Tezra and that's why we leave comments, not answers, when we think someone's asking the wrong questions. There is no merit in then pointing out that comment doesn't answer the question - that is already quite obvious.

Comment: All characters in JavaScript are Unicode. You must mean characters in blocks other than the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block.

Comment: But, back to the motivation for your question: � is used when something has caused data loss, probably reading or writing text bytes using the wrong encoding or character set. How do you observe �? Please show your code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just mean, you should ask why someone is doing something before just saying they are doing it wrong. Without more context, this is actually a pretty reasonable requirement for a form field, and An User never said this was causing a problem. I interpret this as he wants a "clean text" field. An User, for Mike, do you just want 'clean text', or are you just stripping unicode characters to prevent something from breaking? (and if so, what breaks?)

Comment: Thank you @Tezra.I just wanted a clean text field and I was able to achieve it using the pattern /^[\x20-\x7E]*$/

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact about char ranges in Regex; [A-Z] actually matches any character between A and Z in the ascii (and unicode) table! So if you look up an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), the first printable ascii character is tab (followed by !) and the last one is ~. So [\t-~] is a valid regex range that matches the printable range of ascii characters! This is why [A-z] is valid, but [a-Z] isn't.

**TL;DR**
[\t-~] or [!-~]